# Access hidden fields value if its Visibility set to false(using C#)

Tags: c#, javascript, css, visibility, hidden-field

How can I access the content of hidden field, where the hiddenfiled's visibility set to `Visible=false` in the server side using C#. I am not in a situation to use CSS's `display:none` instead of `Visible=false`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `Visible` is `false`, then the control did not go down to the client, so you cannot directly access it from javascript: it simply isn't there.

Equally, since it is a `HiddenField` (i.e.`<input type="hidden"...>`), there is no need to set `display:none` - it will *never* be visible, even if `Visible` is `true` (although, it will be in the source).

So: either set `Visible` to `true`, or come back to the server to get that value.

Comment: Better I store the required value in `Session` and access it from JavaScript. Right ?

Comment: @Rauf you don't give enough context for me to possibly answer that; putting it in a hidden field may be more than sufficient, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 5):

When you set `Visisble=false` on the server side it won't actually render the control in the page so there is no way to get the value on the client side.

If you really can't put the value in the page some other way you could do an AJAX request to get the value when you need it?

Answer (score 2):

You can't - these fields are not being rendered to the client side.