# Use VBA to populate .aspx program - fields disappear

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vba, vbscript

I'm trying to populate several fields in a .aspx program using VBA.

While I can populate fields that have assigned IDs, I'm having a problem related to a button that has no ID or name. By looping though the HTML I can find and click this button, but the hidden fields that are revealed by the click  immediately disappear. Does not throw an error, hidden fields I want to see just flash for an instant on the screen and disappear.

When I step through the code - it works with no problem, but not when I run it.

I thought speed might be the issue but have inserted high levels of `Sleep` just about everywhere and does not fix.

====

Just FYI - In VBScript, I can run this with no problem using the button's function:

```
objIE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "addFileBox();", "javascript"
```

but get "Access Denied" error if I try variations of this code in VBA.

====

Here's the VBA code:

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

    Dim objIE As Object
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate "http://xxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx.aspx"

    While objIE.Busy
      Sleep 100
    Wend

    objIE.Document.getElementById("ddlCategory").Value = "05"    'Works
    objIE.Document.getElementById("txtReference").Value = "150812"   'Works


    'Below added to find and click "Add Doc" button, it has no ID or name
    Dim Document As HTMLDocument
    Dim Elements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim SingleElement As IHTMLElement

    Set Document = objIE.Document
    Set Elements = Document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")

    For Each SingleElement In Elements
         If SingleElement.Value = "Add Doc" Then
            SingleElement.Click
              Exit For
        End If
    Next SingleElement

Sleep 1000
```

How can I fix the VBA code so the fields don't disappear on the .aspx UI?

Comment: `hidden fields I want to see just flash for an instant on the screen and disappear` ... hmmm this sounds strange to me. Hidden field should be hidden and even setting the `visible` property to `true` shouldn't make it visible...[see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553626/access-hidden-fields-value-if-its-visibility-set-to-falseusing-c). Are you sure it is hidden field?

Comment: I may not be using term "hidden" correctly - my experience here is about nil. Trying to say that clicking the button causes a couple of fields to appear on the .aspx UI that were not previously visible. What seems odd is that the VBA code works when I step through it - the fields appear on the UI and they stay there. But when I run the code, I see the fields only for an instant and then they are gone.

Comment: The function `addFileBox()` is called when the button is clicked? If yes, what does this function do?

Comment: The button does call a function. There is quite a bit of code in it, seems to be creating the two fields in question (which are an INPUT TYPE=File box and a combo box). Part of the function code: `var newUploadBox = document.createElement ("input");`

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the code of this function `addFileBox`?

Comment: I'd like to post the full code, but its an in house company program so I better not. I can say the main things happening seem to be the creation of the two fields/elements. In addition to the one noted above, the other is `var newDocumentTypeOther = document.createElement ("input");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129066/discussion-between-dee-and-b-cap).